# A Word To Represent Physical & Mental Attributes

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a game, and at the moment I'm using the word "Attributes" to represent things like: intelligence, strength, dexterity, wisdom, aura, etc.

I wouldn't necessarily call them traits, because there will be a statistic applied to each one of them. Is there a not a *proper* word to represent these?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about choosing the names of things in a program, which is on the explicit list of things that are specifically off-topic here.

Comment: @tchrist Like I told you in the other question, I never said this is a program. Stop making assumptions. It's a story game.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be asking this in one of the gaming SE sites.

Comment: @tchrist which are for referencing only. Since I'm creating one and it doesn't exist yet, My questions would be closed there.

Comment: Gary always called them *character stats*; that seems sufficient.

Comment: Stats is a very broad term. Character stats would also imply skill stats, which is inadequate.

Comment: what do you think about using the word: aptitude ?

Comment: @Xarcell: There *is* http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. I'm not sure if they would want this question, though.

Comment: @MrHen gamedev looks like the exchange site I should be asking this at. Thanks.

Comment: 'Aptitudes' covers skills/abilities: 'a natural ability to do something.
"children with an aptitude for painting and drawing" ' [[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=aptitude+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=aptitude+m&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCggAEAAYsQMYgAQyCggAEAAYsQMYgAQyBggBEEUYOTIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)] But not strength, stamina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most role-playing type games I'm familiar with use the term [attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_%28role-playing_games%29). I can't see why there would be a need to coin a new term.

Comment: This is not an answer. Better off as a comment.

Comment: @Xarcell: Why isn't this an answer? *Attributes* is the common term for what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

demeanor

outward behavior or bearing.

Answer (score -1):

[Matthew 25:14-30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025%3A14-30&version=ASV) is the [parable of the talents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_talents).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talent_%28measurement%29) describes talent as form of measurement of material worth and skill, and hence implies a measure and ranking of both mental and dexterous abilities.

Due to the biblical use, *talent* has also become a measure and ranking of endowment or *giftedness*.

You could choose to use either the term *endowment*, *aptitude* or *talent*, but *talent* has a better classical and mystical ring to the word. One could be endowed with or acquire talent of discernment, wisdom, honour, physical prowess, prophecy, being a friend, being an annoyance, being a blessing, etc.

> [tal•ent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talent) (ˈtæl ənt)
>   n.
>
> 1. a special, often creative natural ability or aptitude: a talent for drawing.
> 2. a person or persons with special ability, esp. in a particular field: the theater's major talents; the local talent.
> 3. a power of mind or body considered as given to a person for use and improvement: so called from the parable in Matt. 25:14–30.
> 4. any of various ancient units of weight, as a unit of the Middle East equal to 3000 shekels, or of Greece equal to 6000 drachmas.
> 5. any of various ancient monetary units equal to the value of a talent weight of gold or silver.
> 6. Obs. inclination or disposition.
>
> [before 900; Middle English, Old English talente < Latin talenta, pl. of talentum < Greek tálanton balance, weight, monetary unit]
>   tal′ent•ed, adj.
>   syn: See ability.
>   *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

Comment: Also, talent is rather apt to be statistically or empirically measured, weighted and ranked,